# Trouble finding limit points of set $\left \{ \frac{1}{n}+\frac{i}{m}: n,m \in \mathbb{Z}_+, i^2=-1 \ \right \}$

Tags: real-analysis

Find the set of limit points of the set $$\left \{ \frac{1}{n}+\frac{i}{m}: n,m \in \mathbb{Z}_+, i^2=-1 \ \right \}$$

Now I think the set of limit points is $$\left [\frac{1}{n},\frac{i}{m}\right ]$$

However I suppose we take the point $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}$, and take the radius of the neighbourhood to be say $$r<\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{1}{6}$$ Then there is no other point from this point inside the neighbourhood. This could be repeated with smaller intervals for all other points apart from points of the form $$\left (0,\frac{i}{m}\right ), \left (\frac{1}{n},0 \right ),(0,0)$$

I think I'm right in giving that as the limit points. If someone could have a look and confirm :)

EDIT: One example I tried to think of as a limit point would be the point $\frac{i}{2}$. You could always add a real component which was extremely small, i.e. $n$ large to construct a point that was always less than a certain radius away. This would be $n>\frac{1}{r}$ for radius $r$.

Comment: The  set you start with is a countable subset of $\mathbb{C}$. The set $(0,1]\times (0,i]$ is an uncountable subset of $\mathbb{C}$. So they can't be equal. Moreover, the set you end up with is not a subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Also, can you give an example of a limit-point different from zero?

Comment: I've added an edit to try to address your comment

Comment: I'm not sure my notation is correct, but I'm trying to say that the limit points arise (I think) when one or more of the components of the complex number are $0$.

Comment: What do you mean by $[\frac{1}{n},\frac{i}{m}]$ ?

Answer (score 1):

It is clear that the set $\{ \frac{1}{n} + \frac{i}{m} \} \cup \{0\} \cup \{\frac{1}{n} \} \cup \{\frac{i}{m}\}$ is contained in the set of limit points.

Pick another point $x = a+bi$ which is not in the above set. Then there is a tiny neighborhood around it which does not contain any other point in the set. The radius of this neighborhood is $\inf\{ |a-1/n|, |b-1/m|, m,n \in \Bbb{Z}_+\}$. Thus any such $x$ is not a limit point.

---

In the above I considered that constant sequences may be allowed, but it seems that this is not the case in the definition of the limit point. This changes a bit the situation. The set of limit points is then $\{0\} \cup \{\frac{1}{n}\} \cup \{\frac{i}{m}\}$. Why are these the only ones? Pick another point $x$ which is different from this. A small enough neighborhood will contain only finitely many points in the original set, and thus such a point is not a limit of any subsequence of the original set.